# Setting up VGG-Face Descriptor in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, torch, face-recognition, pytorch

I've been trying to use the VGG-Face descriptor model (http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/vgg_face/) for a project of mine. All I want to do is to simply obtain the outputs of the network from an input image.

I haven't used any of MatConvNet, Caffe or PyTorch before and so I picked PyTorch at random. It turns out that the model (of class torch.legacy.nn.Sequential.Sequential) was saved in an older version of PyTorch and the syntax was thus slightly different to the ones on PyTorch's documentation.

I was able to load the lua .t7 model like so:

```
vgg_net = load_lua('./vgg_face_torch/VGG_FACE.t7', unknown_classes=True)
```

And loading in the input image:

```
# load image
image = imread('./ak.png')
# convert to tensor
input = torch.from_numpy(image).float()
```

Gleefully, I loaded in the image into the model with much anticipation:

```
# load into vgg_net
output = vgg_net.forward(input)
```

However, my hopes of it cooperating at all was quickly dashed when the code fails to compile. Leaving behind a cryptic error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Documents/python/vgg-face-test/vgg-pytorch.py", line 25, in <module>
    output = vgg_net.forward(input)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/legacy/nn/Module.py", line 33, in forward
    return self.updateOutput(input)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/serialization/read_lua_file.py", line 235, in updateOutput_patch
    return obj.updateOutput(*args)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/legacy/nn/Sequential.py", line 36, in updateOutput
    currentOutput = module.updateOutput(currentOutput)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Of which I am absolutely dumbfounded by.

This is why I sought help on Stackoverflow. I hope someone here could perhaps lend me a hand in setting up the model - not even necessarily in Torch, in fact any working model will do, where I can simply get the description for any particular image.

Answer (score 0):

try `output = vgg_net(input)` without the forward.
This apparently calls a default method defined in the module but I'm having trouble understanding why this is necessary.